# What is the right regular expression for this web link?

Tags: regex

I want to find the regular expression for some web link. Like this:
[example.com/bbsdoc.php?board/Picture](http://example.com/bbsdoc.php?board/Picture)
or
[example.com/bbsdoc.php?board=Picture](http://example.com/bbsdoc.php?board=Picture)
And I test it here: https://regex101.com/

I find that **board\/Picture** matches **board/Picture** in the first link. And **board=Picture** matches the one in the second link.

But how to make a regular expression like below to match the whole link?
**example.com*board\/Picture**
It shows wrong for this one in the test website: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Like [`example\.com\/[^?\s]*\?board[\/=]Picture`](https://regex101.com/r/tA4lW7/1)?

Comment: You seem to assume `*` matches anything, but that's not at all what it does in regex.  Perhaps visit the [regex tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say from 2 links but something like this `example\.com.*?\W+board[\/=]Picture` will work

Comment: What is the purpose of using `\W+` after lazy dot matching pattern `.*?`?

Comment: to check for `&amp;` and `&` or `/` - as I wrote - hard to tell from 2 links what formats are

Comment: You could replace `\W+` with `\b` I believe.

Comment: true, there is always more than one way to skin a cat :)

Comment: Yeah, but some are less costly.